# How to read inner lists on a JSON file and convert it to a data frame?

Tags: r, json

I am trying to read a json file and extract some fieds to create a dataframe.

I have tried several times, but I couldn' get  the variable "Product Type", because it is an inner list.

I need to extract the following variables:
User Name, User e-mail and Product Type.

Name and e-mail were easy to get, but could someone please help me to get the Product Type?

Thanks a lot

```
require("jsonlite")
json_file <-NULL
json_file <- fromJSON("RStudio/teste2.json")

json_file<- json_file$data$


json_file$data <- lapply(json_file$data, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})

json_file$data<-as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", json_file$data))

test <- cbind.data.frame(
                          json_file$data$user$name,
                          json_file$data$user$email,
                          json_file$data$user$Prducts$Type

                          )
```

Here is an example of the json I am readind

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK"
  },
  "data": [
   {
  "user": {
    "id": "122344535423sfdf",
    "name": "John Silva",
    "email": "john@mail.com",
    "birthdate": "1982-10-12"

  },

  "products": [
    {
      "id": 101,
      "type": "meals",
      "name": "salad",
      "price": 34567

    }
  ]


},
{
  "user": {
    "id": "1rwrwtry533ef",
    "name": "Mary Gomes",
    "email": "mary@mail.com",
    "birthdate": "1989-12-15"

  },

  "products": [
    {
      "id": 101,
      "type": "drinks",
      "name": "orange juice",
      "price": 199

    }
  ]


}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load the package required to read JSON files.
library("rjson")

# Give the input file name to the function.
result <- fromJSON(file = "input.json")

# Convert JSON file to a data frame.
json_data_frame <- as.data.frame(result)
```

Now json_data_frame will contain the exact data frame of the json as you required.

You can look at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_json_files.htm

Comment: Thank you :)

But it didn't work with the node Products. Because it is nested.